# Open external apps and web pages in ZK

Tags: java, tomcat, web, zk

Is possible to create a   or similar in ZK that contains a url to another project or web? I explain:

The question is if it would be possible to press a button to open a window or a div which contains, for example, a Wikipedia article or a HTML file of other project inside the server. A zk component what contains a url content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZK [Iframe](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.3/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Iframe.html) is what you want. This [demo](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/composite/iframe) might help.